# How to list logon denied from logonhours within powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I set logonhours to (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), so login is disabled.
Now I would like to know a list with that values through powershell:

```
$logonTest3 = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"


 $users = Get-aduser -Identity hugo
 ForEach($user in $users)  
{  

    [string]$hours = get-aduser $user  -Properties LogonHours | select -ExpandProperty LogonHours
    
    
    if ($hours -eq $logonTest3){
    write-host $user "- Login disabled"}
}
```

But it seems that $LogonTest3 is empty.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

LogonHours is composed of a set of 21 **bytes**. You define your variable `$logonTest3` as a **string** with 21 "0" characters separated by spaces.
Also when you are reading the LogonHours property, you are stringyfying it by using a `[string]` cast but that will never return a value comparable to your `$logonTest3` string..

There's a very good read about the meaning of these bytes here: [Manage AD User Logon Hours using PowerShell](https://www.powershellcenter.com/2021/03/09/manage-ad-user-logon-hours-using-powershell/)

As for your code, if you want to check if all 21 bytes of the logonHours property are set to zero, you can do:

```
$userToFind = 'hugo'
# try and find the user also gathering its LogonHours property
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$userToFind'" -Properties LogonHours -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($user) {
    # test if the property has been set. If not set, the user is allowed to login anytime of the week
    if ($null -ne $user.LogonHours -and @($user.LogonHours).Count) {
        # initialize a variable
        $loginAllowed = $false
        # loop through the 21 bytes and exit the loop if we found a non-zero byte
        foreach ($byte in $user.LogonHours) { 
            if ($byte -ne 0) { 
                $loginAllowed = $true  # set the flag to $true
                break                  # and exit the loop
            }
        }
        if (!$loginAllowed) {
            "User $userToFind - Login disabled"
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User $userToFind does not exist.."
}
```

Comment: I tried for different users in which logonhours is set to "0" and for users without any entries for logonhours. And for both type of users it seems that logonhours is without any entries

Comment: @Ale_noob I have changed the test if the property has been set now by using `.Count`. please can you try again?

Comment: Hey @Theo, I tried your code, but I get per each user the  same result

Comment: @Ale_noob added extra test for not set: `$null -ne $user.LogonHours`

Comment: I didn't get any results. It seems that logonHours is null expression:
`write-output $user.LogonHours.getType()`
**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.**

Comment: Make sure that property [is populated in AD](https://www.powershellcenter.com/2021/03/09/manage-ad-user-logon-hours-using-powershell/) for this test user 'hugo'