# How to list users with logonhours denied

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need a list of users with the logonhours set to denied. I found another question ([68558481](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558481/how-to-list-logon-denied-from-logonhours-within-powershell)) that partially got me there but I seem to be doing something wrong when trying to loop through my group.

```
$userToFind = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "AD group" | Sort-Object samAccountName | Select SamAccountName
# try and find the user also gathering its LogonHours property
Foreach ($username in $userToFind){
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -Properties LogonHours -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($user) {
    # test if the property has been set. If not set, the user is allowed to login anytime of the week
    if ($null -ne $user.LogonHours -and @($user.LogonHours).Count) {
        # initialize a variable
        $loginAllowed = $false
        # loop through the 21 bytes and exit the loop if we found a non-zero byte
        foreach ($byte in $user.LogonHours) { 
            if ($byte -ne 0) { 
                $loginAllowed = $true  # set the flag to $true
                break                  # and exit the loop
            }
        }
        if (!$loginAllowed) {
            "User $username - Login disabled"
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User $username does not exist.."
}
}
```

My results for this is all users do not exist. Where am I going wrong?

|

Comment: Change `Select SamAccountName` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName`. Everything should work from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `$userToFind` is an object or array of objects which's property is `SamAccountName`, so when you use it in your filter `"SamAccountName -eq '$username'"`, the result is the stringification of each object:

```bash
$username = [pscustomobject]@{
    samAccountName = 'someuser'
}

"SamAccountName -eq '$username'" # => SamAccountName -eq '@{samAccountName=someuser}'
```

What you want to do instead is get the value of each object, a string or array of strings in this case:

```bash
$username = [pscustomobject]@{
    samAccountName = 'someuser'
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samAccountName

"SamAccountName -eq '$username'" # => SamAccountName -eq 'someuser'
```

You can also use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) instead of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2), so in your code it would be:

```bash
$userToFind = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "AD group" | Sort-Object samAccountName).SamAccountName
```

As for the current code, you could make an improvement by only searching for users **member of the group which's `logonHours` attribute is populated**. That way, there is no need to check if the user has the attribute set and no need to check if the user was found or not.

```bash
# get the DN of the group
$group = (Get-ADGroup -Identity "AD group").DistinguishedName
$param = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(&(memberof=$group)(logonhours=*))"
    Properties = "logonHours"
}
# enumerate all users members of this group which's attribute `LogonHours` is set
foreach($user in Get-ADUser @param) {
    $loginAllowed = $false
    foreach($byte in $user.LogonHours) {
        if ($byte -ne 0) {
            $loginAllowed = $true
            break
        }
    }
    if (-not $loginAllowed) {
        "User {0} - Login disabled" -f $user.SamAccountName
    }
}
```